How to improve performance of unicast to broadcast UDP packet transformation on OpenWrt?
Background
We have some devices sending unicast UDP packets which we want to receive on multiple computers by transforming those packets to broadcast. We can't make any changes to the devices sending the packets nor the computers receiving the data. The UDP packets are sent with the same headers and packet size (less than 1500 bytes). The transmitting devices are on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and the receiving computers are on the 192.168.40.0/24 subnet.
Current Setup
We need a standalone device that can forward the unicast packets to the 192.168.40.0/24 subnet as broadcast packets. The current approach I use is to reuse an RB760iGS RouterBoard, which has an SFP port and 5 gigabit Ethernet ports. The incoming packets arrive at the SFP port and the receiving computers are connected to the Ethernet ports. The receiving computers will not send any data back
The bandwidth is relatively high at around 250 Mbps, so I wrote an eBPF XDP program to transform the packets:
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>

#define IP_HLEN  sizeof(struct iphdr)   // IP header length (assuming no options)
#define UDP_HLEN sizeof(struct udphdr)  // UDP header length
#define TOTAL_HLEN (ETH_HLEN + IP_HLEN + UDP_HLEN + 24) // Total headers length

#define TARGET_INTERFACE_INDEX 9  // interface index for br-lan

#define NEW_IP_DST      0xFF28A8C0 // 192.168.40.255 (network byte order)
#define NEW_UDP_DST_PORT 0xB315
#define CHECKSUM_DIFF 0xFFFFD828 // pcn_csum_add(0xC0A80128, ~0xC0A828FF & 0xFFFFFFFF);

static inline __u16 pcn_csum_add(__u32 csum, __u32 addend) {
    __u32 result;
    __u8 carry = __builtin_uadd_overflow(csum, addend, &result);
    result += carry;  // Add carry if overflow occurred
    return result;
}

SEC("xdp_redirect")
int xdp_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;

    if (data + TOTAL_HLEN > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;

    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    struct iphdr *ip = data + ETH_HLEN;
    struct udphdr *udp = data + ETH_HLEN + IP_HLEN;

    ip->daddr = NEW_IP_DST;
    udp->dest = NEW_UDP_DST_PORT;

    *((__u32*)&eth->h_dest[0]) = 0xffffffff;  // First four bytes
    *((__u16*)&eth->h_dest[4]) = 0xffff;      // Last two bytes

    // The CHECKSUM_DIFF is a precomputed value based on the change from the original destination IP
    ip->check = bpf_htons(pcn_csum_add(bpf_ntohs(ip->check), CHECKSUM_DIFF));

    // Redirect packet to the specified interface index
    return bpf_redirect(TARGET_INTERFACE_INDEX, 0);
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

This works when I only have one device connected on the br-lan interface, but when I connect more devices, a lot of packets are dropped. The router's CPU is a 880MHz dual-core processor with 256MB of RAM.
Questions

Are there additional optimizations that could be done to the XDP program?
Any settings that could be done to optimize for high bandwidth (like using a more efficient qdisc)?
Is there a router that supports OpenWrt with better performance than the RB760iGS?

Thank you for your advice!
(Update: I was able to handle up to 250mbps without drops and multiple receivers if I put a gigabit switch between the router and the receivers, the drawback with this approach is that I need 2 devices to handle this task instead of 1 and also additional latency is introduced. I am still looking for optimizations to be able to use one device)
